# PostgreSQL Crosstab

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone help me and tell me why this crosstab query wouldn't be working?  The error I'm currently getting is "[42703] ERROR: column "1" does not exist" . Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
select * from
  crosstab('select
source
,status
,sum(CASE
  when cast(rejected as int) = 1 
      then (cast(articles as int) * cast(rejected as int))
  else cast(articles as int)
  end) as Units

from summary.itemdata
where

 first_owner = "1"
and created >= "2017-01-01"
and ownerships = "1"
group BY
  source
,status
order by source, status')
as final_result(source text, 
               discarded int, 
               "pick-job" int, 
               missing int, 
               "weigh-end" int, 
               received int, 
               shipped int, 
               "cat-end" int, 
               packed int, 
               picking int)
```

Comment: Double quotes `"` in the where part are most likely, if not for sure, causing the error. Use escaped single quotes `''`. looks similar but behaves completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing the query as a string parameter to `crosstab` the `1` between double quotes is interpreted as column name while your intention is to be a string value for the `where` condition.
This is accomplished using single quotes but need to be escaped to be inside a string. One way to escape a single quote is using another single quote before it.

Change this part

```
where

 first_owner = "1"
and created >= "2017-01-01"
and ownerships = "1"
```

replacing double quotes by escaped single quotes

```
where

 first_owner = ''1''
and created >= ''2017-01-01''
and ownerships = ''1''
```

It looks the same but the meaning is completely different.